# Microsoft Access Count unique values per id

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have an access database that has an id referring to a customer who has trucks of different sizes. currently the table looks something like this:

```
id.....tire size
1......30
1......30
1......31
1......31
2......32
```

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
id.....30.....31.....32
1......2......2......0
2......0......0......0
```

where it counts the number of occurrences of a specific tire size and inputs it into the respective tire size column.

Comment: Run the Query assistant for Crosstab queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to display the data as you have written it, you will need to do a crosstab query. The code below should achieve what you want

```
TRANSFORM Nz(Count([YourTable].[Tire Size]),0) AS [CountOfTire Size]
SELECT [YourTable].[ID]
FROM [YourTable]
GROUP BY [YourTable].[ID]
PIVOT [YourTable].[Tire Size];
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be a query like:

```
select tire_size, COUNT(id) from mytable
GROUP BY tire_size
```

*(I put the "special magic" parts of that query in UPPER CASE for emphasis.)*

In the MS-Access query-builder, grouping features are accessed by clicking a button that looks vaguely like an "E" *(actually, a Greek "epsilon" character),* if I recall correctly. This adds a new "grouping" row to the query-builder grid.

This will produce (as you will quickly see) a row-by-row result with tire-size and the count of id's for that tire-size.

Many other variations of this are possible.  Read the MS-Access on-line help which discusses this feature: they did a very good job with it.

The essential idea is the `GROUP BY` clause: this says that each distinct value of `tire_size` forms a "group." (Yes, you can `GROUP BY` more than one column, in which each unique combination of values forms one group.) Then, you specify so-called *"domain aggregate functions,* such as `COUNT(), AVG(), SUM()`, to produce summary statistics for each group.

Every `GROUP BY` column must appear in the `SELECT` clause, and every other item that appears there *must* be a domain aggregate function. *(Which, if you think about it, makes perfect sense ...)*

(Fortunately, MS-Access's query builder does a good job of "hiding" all that. You can build a grouping-query interactively, thanks to that "epsilon" button.  But it's useful then to look at the "SQL View" to see what it did in SQL terms.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'GROUP BY' aggregator

You'll need something like this:

```
SELECT 
tyre_size,
count(id) 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY
tire_size
```